# How to Iterate through Object in JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, object, for-loop

I am having to solve a problem involving code in both JS and PHP.  For some reason, whenever this code executes, it puts the first entry in all the rows of the table instead of iterating through each entry and putting all of them in the rows.  I would appreciate someone's help in giving me insights into how to fix this issue.  Can this be fixed with just a "for in" loop?  Thanks in advance.

```js
<?php include('../../functions.php');

    $query = "
    SELECT
    *
    FROM
    plobby
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.UID = plobby.UID
    WHERE
    `LID` = '". preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $_POST['id']) ."';
    ";

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(`LID`) AS `x` FROM `snipe`.`plobby` WHERE LID = '".$_POST['id']."';";
        
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $rst = $db->query($sql);

    $cnt = 0;

    if($rst->num_rows > 0)
        while($row = $rst->fetch_assoc())
            $cnt = $row["x"];

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
        for($i = 1;$i<= $cnt;$i++)
            echo json_encode($result->fetch_assoc());
    else 
        echo json_encode([]);
?>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the object to which the above loop is referring:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 var state = {};
 for($i = 1;$i <= <?php echo getLobbytPlayers($_GET['id']);?>;$i++ ){
  
  var reloadTable = function (data) {
   if ($.data(state) == $.data(data)) {
    return;
   }
  
   $('#js-lobby-table').empty();
  
   $.each(data, function (rowNumber, rowData) {
   
    var row = $('<tr>');
   
    console.log(data);
   
    // Player
    row.append($('<td>', {
     'html': data.eName
    }));
   
    // Status
    row.append($('<td>', {
     'html': data.gameID == "000" ? 'waiting' : 'ingame'
    }));
   
    // Win %
    row.append($('<td>', {
     'html': 'TODO'
    }));
   
    // Games
    row.append($('<td>', {
     'html': 'TODO'
    }));
   
    // K/D
    row.append($('<td>', {
     'html': 'TODO'
    }));
    
    $('#js-lobby-table').append(row);
   });
   
   // Set the current table state.
   state = data;
  };
 }
 
 setInterval(function () {
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/lobby/api/table.php',
   data: {
    id: '<?= $_GET['id'] ?>'
   },
   success: reloadTable,
   dataType: 'json'
  });
 }, 10);
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why do you need a `while` loop for the `COUNT(*)` query? It always returns eactly 1 row.

Comment: On the javascript code, you are using the $.each jquery function to iterate on your data object, but you are not using the rowData item you declared in every iteration. So you need to change all your 'html': data.{property} for 'html': rowData.{property}, ie. rowData.name, etc. Assuming your data object has all the values from your $result query.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `json_encode()` multiple times. The response has to contain a single JSON object, not multiple objects. You need to put all the results in an array, and call `json_encode()` on that array at the end.

There's also no need to get the count first. Just call `fetch_assoc()` until you get all the results.

```
<?php include('../../functions.php');

    $query = "
    SELECT
    *
    FROM
    plobby
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.UID = plobby.UID
    WHERE
    `LID` = '". preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $_POST['id']) ."';
    ";

    $result = $db->query($query);

    $rows = [];

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your swift response.  The only thing that confuses me, though, is about the "$rows[]" part.  What is the difference between writing that and writing just "$rows"?